# Nested list inside of TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch

I've started a project with sencha touch (my first real experience with JS), and I'm afraid I've bitten off more than I can chew..

I've created most of my app but I'm having a problem trying to put a Nested list inside of a tab panel. I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRootNode' of undefined.

And here's how I'm trying to insert it:

```
{
title: 'Settings',
iconCls: 'settings',
layout: 'card',
items: [nestedPanel]
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like :

```
App.views.MyNestedList = Ext.extend(Ext.NestedList, {
    iconCls : '',
    iconMask : true, 
    title : '',
    store : '',
    itemTpl : '',
});
Ext.reg('MyNestedList', App.views.MyNestedList);

App.views.myTabs = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel,{
    items : [
        {xtype : 'MyNestedList'}
    ]
});
```